# Child sites are adding to parent global navigation

Tags: navigation

After creating child site are being added to parent site global navigation.
Both(child and parent) are publishing sites.
Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

I have found that 50 child sites are added to TopNavigationBar.So i have 7 static items displayed in bar and 50 more items that exist in TopNavigation, but are not displayed/

The problem seems to be in "IncludeInGlobalNavigation" property of the child site/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in child site settings: "PublishingWeb.IncludeInCurrentNavigation" and  "PublishingWeb.IncludeInGlobalNavigation".
With these settings child sited adding itself to parent navigation.
And 50 is the default count of maximum dynamic nodes, adding to to parent navigation.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new sub-site you should have an option to inherit the parent sites Top Navigation and whether or not you want to add the new site to the navigation bar.

If you want to edit a navigation bar...

1. Go to site actions
2. Site Settings
3. Under Look and Feel select the Top link bar option
4. Edit it as needed.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem was in child site settings: "PublishingWeb.IncludeInCurrentNavigation"  and "PublishingWeb.IncludeInGlobalNavigation". With these settings child sited adding itself to parent navigation. And 50 is the default count of maximum adding dynamic nodes.